# All Spring batch Partition Threads - Read same data instead of reading data from its range

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have person table in Postgres db. I am using Spring batch, and reading data from postgreSQL using JdbcCursorItemReader
I have created Master Step and Slave step for the partitioning and given a partitioner but all my threads are reading the same data. Hence taking longer time.

This is my actual BatchConfig file

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private CustomWriter writer;
    

    private static final String OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION = null;

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters[query]}") String query,
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[fromId]}") String fromId,
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[toId]}") String toId) {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> cursorItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        cursorItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        query = "select * from person";
        cursorItemReader.setSql(query);
        cursorItemReader.setSaveState(true);
        cursorItemReader.setRowMapper(new PersonRowMapper());
        return cursorItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public PersonItenProcessor processor() {
        return new PersonItenProcessor();
    }

    // Master
    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .partitioner(workerStep().getName(), partitioner())
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .step(workerStep())
                .gridSize(3)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();
    }
    
    // Slave
        @Bean
        public Step workerStep() {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("workerStep")
                    .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                    .<Person, Person>chunk(4)
                    .reader(reader(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION))
                    //.faultTolerant().skipPolicy(rowSkipper())
                    //.skipLimit(2).skip(SQLException.class)
                    .processor(processor())
                    .writer(writer)
                    .taskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()).
                    build();
        }


    @Bean
    public SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(2);
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Partitioner partitioner() {
        return new RangePartitioner();      
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Job exportPerosnJob() {
        String query = "select * from person";
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("exportPeronJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1()).end().build();
    }
}
```

This is Partitioner File

```
public class RangePartitioner implements Partitioner {

    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> result 
        = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
        
        int range = 10;
        int fromId = 1;
        int toId = range;
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= gridSize; i++) {
            ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();

            System.out.println("\nStarting : Thread" + i);
            System.out.println("fromId : " + fromId);
            System.out.println("toId : " + toId);

            value.putInt("fromId", fromId);
            value.putInt("toId", toId);

            // give each thread a name, thread 1,2,3
            value.putString("name", "Thread" + i);

            result.put("partition" + i, value);

            fromId = toId + 1;
            toId += range;

        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: And it should because? You aren't using anything from the limit in  your query, so it will just query all the data.

Comment: Thankyou @M.Deinum for having a look at my issue. I would like to re-iterate. so, The problem is each partition thread is reading the same data although it should partition the data across different ranges and each partition should read different data

Comment: @Payalsahita You need to use `fromId` and `toId` in where clause of your query. `query = "select * from person";`  This link should help you. https://mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-partitioning-example/

Comment: As stated you aren't limiting anything. You have a query that reads everything instead of using the range you specify. You still have to do that yourself in the query using the range you specify for the partition.